# Linq DataContext.CreateDatabase() force SQL Server 2005

Tags: database, linq, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql

I'm using Linq `DataContext.CreateDatabase()` to generate a database. Currently it's generating a SQL Server 2008 database. I would like to know if it's possible to make `CreateDatabase()` generate a SQL Server 2005 database?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick check of the DataContext object in Visual Studio and it doesn't appear to be SQL version specific.  So I would assume if you point the DataContext object at a SQL 2005 instance it would create the database just fine on SQL 2005.